# XSLT for each loop not working

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xml file like this

```
<generic-cv:generic-cv xmlns:generic-cv="http://www.cihr-irsc.gc.ca/generic-cv/1.0.0" lang="en" dateTimeGenerated="2014-05-30 11:40:50">
    <section id="f589cbc028c64fdaa783da01647e5e3c" label="Personal Information">
        <section id="2687e70e5d45487c93a8a02626543f64" label="Identification" recordId="4f7c2ebd789f407b939e05664f6aa7c0">
            <field id="ee8beaea41f049d8bcfadfbfa89ac09e" label="Title">
                <lov id="00000000000000000000000000000318">Mr.</lov>
            </field>
            <field id="5c6f17e8a67241e19667815a9e95d9d0" label="Family Name">
                <value type="String">ali</value>
            </field>
            <field id="98ad36fee26a4d6b8953ea764f4fed04" label="First Name">
                <value type="String">Hara</value>
            </field>

        </section>
        <section id="2687e70e5d45487c93a8a02626543f64" label="Identification" recordId="4f7c2ebd789f407b939e05664f6aa7c0">
            <field id="ee8beaea41f049d8bcfadfbfa89ac09e" label="Title">
                <lov id="00000000000000000000000000000318">Mr.</lov>
            </field>
            <field id="5c6f17e8a67241e19667815a9e95d9d0" label="Family Name">
                <value type="String">fara</value>
            </field>
            <field id="98ad36fee26a4d6b8953ea764f4fed04" label="First Name">
                <value type="String">hhh</value>
            </field>

        </section>
    </section>
</generic-cv:generic-cv>
```

and an xslt file like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Xml Convertor</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2><b> Personal Information</b></h2>
                <xsl:for-each select=".//section[@id='2687e70e5d45487c93a8a02626543f64']" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Name: <xsl:value-of select=".//field[@id='98ad36fee26a4d6b8953ea764f4fed04']/value" />, <xsl:value-of select=".//field[@id='5c6f17e8a67241e19667815a9e95d9d0']/value" /></li>

                </ul>       
                </xsl:for-each>                    

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want loop through each section with a certain id number and print out the names in a list. Should look something like this

```
Hara
hhh
```

What i have tried so far is not working. Would someone be able to take a look and see what I did wrong

Comment: "not working" is not a good description of a problem. Describe *exactly* what you get and what you expect to get. BTW, if that's really your XSLT code, then it's not working because it's cut off in the middle. You need to close all the open elements. And your elements must be properly nested: you cannot open `<ul>`  inside `<xsl:for-each>` and close it outside.

Comment: Your XSLT is not well-formed because you also have an empty `<xsl:for-each>` tag. Remove the `/` from the end of the start tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Xml Convertor</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2><b> Personal Information</b></h2>
          <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//section[@id='2687e70e5d45487c93a8a02626543f64']" >

                <li>Name: <xsl:value-of   select=".//field[@id='98ad36fee26a4d6b8953ea764f4fed04']/value" />, <xsl:value-of select=".//field[@id='5c6f17e8a67241e19667815a9e95d9d0']/value" /></li>


            </xsl:for-each>                    
            </ul> 
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have check it with [XSLT Tryit Editor from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) and this produces:

Personal Information

Name: Hara, ali

Name: hhh, fara

Answer (score -1):

In your for-each loop you need to select the `First Name` and `Family Name` fields, instead of ids, as shown below:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//section[@id='2687e70e5d45487c93a8a02626543f64']" >
    <li><xsl:value-of select="field[@label='First Name']/value" />,<xsl:value-of select="field[@label='Family Name']/value" /></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```